# Random unguessable primary key which preserves correct order

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want primary keys in my table to be random and unguessable while still preserving correct order (order in which documents were inserted to database). Firebase uses this algorithm: https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11. Is it a good idea to port it to `psql` or `plv8` for example and use in postgres to generate primary keys for a table? Or maybe there is other solution out of the box in PG?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: It will be id used for REST API endpoints like `/users/abcdefgh123343435` - I want to avoid auto increment integers...

Comment: Why do you have the requirement of being orderable?  To me it seems that you want to combine too much into the PK.  For identifying a given row, a UUID is more than enough, for ordering one usually uses a creation timestamp or something else that has real meaning.

Comment: You can use a composite `(a,b)` primary key. `a` being a normal auto-incrementing sequence and `b` a random integer. You could also have a computed `2^32 * a + b` column for display purposes. It will be strictly increasing and "unguessable".

Comment: Or something like this: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ff7c3/1) (it needs adjustment to get full 32 bits or randomness and probably more refinements).

Comment: Why don't you look into Row Security instead?

Comment: I's not about security - I just want to normalize primary keys visible by end user - it would be best if all keys were of same length. I think I will just use normal auto increment PK (for internal joins), UUIDV4 in unique column as "fake" PK visible for user, and additional "createdAt" column for ordering rows as they were created.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.

If you want to make a user-unique-and-crazy-key don't use the primary key of the table, create another column with this kind of data and you can generate a unique code using md5 of the unix microtime for example.

The Human world are strange for databases, believe me or not! Let the keys to be keys, its nice and faster to table relationships.

And for any user or system search you use another column, its very like to want to relationship users by using a person one identification code, so you change the country and discovery the code repeats, and all your database is lost. You want a unique crazy code, but it does not mean nothing for your machine, how your machine will work for nothing to make your relationships working. For relationships use things that your machine can really understand, in another words: Use sequential numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a `SEQUENCE` and advance it randomly with function `random()` between the inserts, like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE serial_id;
INSERT INTO your_table (id, name) VALUES (nextval('serial_id'), 'textext');
SELECT nextval('serial_id'), generate_series(1,(random()*10)::integer);
INSERT INTO your_table (id, name) VALUES (nextval('serial_id'), 'textext');
```

- Here multiplication by ten makes the sequence advance in random steps between less than 10
- If you replace 10 with 10 000 you will get random gaps smaller than 10 000.
- You can use the same principle with the data type `SERIAL` as long as you dig out the name of the automatically created sequence and use it in the `SELECT` statement above.

Comment: It does not seem good idea for me: still this numbers will be auto_incremented, just with a gap <= 10.

Comment: With that one `SELECT` statement you effectively create a random gap between id:s. You have to have some kind incrementation to preserve order...